# click event for list group not triggering when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm new to JQuery so maybe my syntax isn't correct but I can't trigger any click event for a bootstrap list group, when I select something from the list. I don't know if it makes a difference but the list group is inside a bootstrap popover.

I have tried both methods here.

```js
$('#eventList').on('click', '.list-group-item', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //code here
});

$(".list-group-item").click(function() {
  // code here
});
```

```html
<div id="events-popover-head" class="hide">Events</div>
<div id="events-popover-content" class="hide">
  <ul id="eventList" class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this code is working  for me

Answer (score 5):

That code is correct and works fine.

It's not working in your case because `'#eventList'` doesn't exist at the time you're adding the listener.

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '#eventList .list-group-item', function(e) {
```

Comment: what is the difference between $('body').on and $(document).on ?

Comment: from this site http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-body-on-document-on/ it says document is faster, so should I use document instead of body?

Comment: @user1186050 There's virtually no difference. Yeah go with whatever's faster. I'll update my answer to use `document` actually

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working 100% fine here https://jsfiddle.net/bkf7y6q7/

Are you sure you included the following in your html file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/du92ucfm/1/

This is working , is there anything else you are asking ?
can you provide a specific code related to bootstrap.js

```
$('#eventList').on('click', '.list-group-item', function(e) {
  console.log('i am clicked 1');
});
$(".list-group-item").click(function() {
 console.log("i am clicked 2");
});
```